# Can protobuf-net serialize MessageContracts as a replacement for the DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, wcf, protobuf-net

I can't seem to find documentation on this anywhere, though [this discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f758f5fa-3c68-47ef-b390-e7cbccecf209/is-there-a-messagecontractserializer?forum=wcf) seems to suggest messaging will always be a WCF affair...

Can a `MessageContract` be serialized with protobuf-net? If so, are there special decorations for `MessageHeader` and `MessageBodyMember`?

Comment: So you don't want to send this over the wire, or you don't want to use WCF, its hard to know specifically what you want to achieve

Comment: Though WCF defines a use case for _binary serialization_, particularly over a corporate LAN using TCP binding it encourages high-level non-binary specifically via SOAP for best interopabiltiy.  To use low-level binary payloads everywhere  via protobuf  you should just do away with WCF because it will be at odds to your already chosen goal

Comment: As far as I know, MessageFormatter interface is used for custom message formatter. Whether this could change the way of message serialization and deserialization?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/custom-message-formatters

Comment: @TheGeneral It's for streaming over WCF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf-net only know about data-contracts, not message-contracts. So: no, basically.